# Using tf extract_image_patches for input to a CNN?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I want to extract patches from my original images to use them as input for a CNN.
After a little research I found a way to extract patches with
`tensorflow.compat.v1.extract_image_patches`.

Since these need to be reshaped to "image format" I implemented a method reshape_image_patches to reshape them and store the reshaped patches in an array.

```
image_patches2 = []

def reshape_image_patches(image_patches, sess, ksize_rows, ksize_cols):
    a = sess.run(tf.shape(image_patches))
    nr, nc = a[1], a[2]
    for i in range(nr):
      for j in range(nc):
        patch = tf.reshape(image_patches[0,i,j,], [ksize_rows, ksize_cols, 3])
        image_patches2.append(patch)
    return image_patches2
```

How can I use this in combination with Keras generators to make these patches the input of my CNN?

Edit 1:

I have tried the approach in [Load tensorflow images and create patches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64326029/load-tensorflow-images-and-create-patches)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    <directory>,
    label_mode=None,
    seed=1,
    subset='training',
    validation_split=0.1,
    image_size=(900, 900))

get_patches = lambda x: (tf.reshape(
    tf.image.extract_patches(
        x,
        sizes=[1, 16, 16, 1],
        strides=[1, 8, 8, 1],
        rates=[1, 1, 1, 1],
        padding='VALID'),  (111*111, 16, 16, 3)))

dataset = dataset.map(get_patches)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=.1, hspace=.2)
images = next(iter(dataset))
for index, image in enumerate(images):
    ax = plt.subplot(2, 2, index + 1)
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

In line: images = next(iter(dataset)) I get the error: InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 302800896 values, but the requested shape has 9462528
[[{{node Reshape}}]]

Does somebody know how to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load tensorflow images and create patches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64326029/load-tensorflow-images-and-create-patches)

Comment: Thanks! It looks way more convenient than my approach. Still how do I use the part of get_patches if I use a generator. To my understanding with a generator the images are not all loaded at the beginning and thus I can not use get_patches on them right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tf.reshape` does not change the order of or **the total number of elements in the tensor**. The error as states, you are trying to reduce total number of elements from 302800896 to 9462528 . You are using `tf.reshape` in `lambda` function.

In below example, I have recreated your scenario where I have the given the `shape` argument as `2` for `tf.reshape` which doesn't accommodate all the elements of original tensor, thus throws the error -

**Code -**

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
t1 = tf.Variable([1,2,2,4,5,6])

t2 = tf.reshape(t1, 2)
```

**Output -**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-0ff1d701ff22> in <module>()
      3 t1 = tf.Variable([1,2,2,4,5,6])
      4 
----> 5 t2 = tf.reshape(t1, 2)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 6 values, but the requested shape has 2 [Op:Reshape]
```

`tf.reshape` should be in such a way that the arrangement of elements can change but total number of elements must remain the same. So the fix would be to change the shape to `[2,3]` -

**Code -**

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
t1 = tf.Variable([1,2,2,4,5,6])

t2 = tf.reshape(t1, [2,3])
print(t2)
```

**Output -**

```
tf.Tensor(
[[1 2 2]
 [4 5 6]], shape=(2, 3), dtype=int32)
```

To solve your problem, either extract patches(`tf.image.extract_patches`) of size that you are trying to `tf.reshape` OR change the `tf.reshape` to size of extract patches.

Will also suggest you to look into other `tf.image` functionality like [tf.image.central_crop](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/central_crop) and [tf.image.crop_and_resize](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/crop_and_resize).