# Why are my images loaded into a dataset all white?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

I created a dataset using my images:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    <directory>,
    label_mode=None,
    seed=1,
    subset='training',
    validation_split=0.1,
    image_size=(900, 900))

images = next(iter(dataset))
print(tf.shape(images))
```

I get the output:
Found 209 files belonging to 1 classes.
Using 189 files for training.
tf.Tensor([ 32 900 900   3], shape=(4,), dtype=int32)

Now I want to look at one images with:

```
plt.imshow(images[19])
plt.show()
```

As output I get:
Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers).

And also a plain white image as an output.

I am sure that the images loaded into the dataset are not plain white. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `dataset` is a `tf.data.Dataset` so you can use this visualization function.
https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/visualization/show_examples

```
tfds.visualization.show_examples(
    ds: tf.data.Dataset,
    ds_info: tfds.core.DatasetInfo,
    **options_kwargs
)
```

implemented this way:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

ds, info = tfds.load(<your dataset name>, split='train', with_info=True)
fig = tfds.show_examples(ds, info)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, but my dataset is "not found". Also I really just want to know why my images are shown in plain white colors and how to fix it.

Comment: thats probably because matplotlib is not able to load your tf.tensors as images. Thats why you should use the tensorflow visualization functions. check out the tutorial provided on that link to find out more

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to use the methods mentioned above but none of them worked the way i wanted. What you can do is change the `interpolation` to `"nearest"` default is `"bilinear"`:

Try this:

```py
ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory = directory, # path to images
    ....
    color_mode="rgb",
    interpolation="nearest",
    follow_links=False,
)
```

Then to display an image:

```py
for image, label in ds:
    pass

plt.imshow(image[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question but franky I prefer to use the ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory, It allows you to rescale  images, augment the images and the output of the generator is easy to use. Documentation is [here.](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/)  For your application, code would be :

```
data_gen=tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255,
    validation_split=.01)
train_gen=data_gen.flow_from_directory(
    directory= r'c:\your_directory',
    target_size=(900,900),
    class_mode="categorical",
    batch_size=32,
    shuffle=True,
    seed=123,    
    subset='training')
valid_gen=data_gen.flow_from_directory(
    directory= r'c:\your_directory',
    target_size=(900,900),
    class_mode="categorical",
    batch_size=32,
    shuffle=False,
    seed=123,    
    subset='validation')
tr_images, tr_labels=next (train_gen) # generate a batch of 32 training images, and labels
val_images, val_labels=next(valid_gen)
print('tr_images.shape = ', tr_images.shape)
# result will be tr_images.shape =  (32, 900, 900, 3)
image1=tr_images[0]
plt.imshow(image1)
plt.show()
# result will be showing the image
# other useful things available
class_dict=train_gen.class_indices # a dictionary where key is the text class name and value is integer label of the class
print (class_dict)
labels= train_gen.labels # a sequential list of all the generator labels
file_names= test_gen.filenames  # a sequential list of all the generator file names
# hope this helps
```

Comment: Thanks, the thing is that I want to extract patches from my images and therefore use the map function as shown in (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64326029/load-tensorflow-images-and-create-patches). Is there a way to do this with a generator?

Answer (score 0):

Transfer them to numpy and cast to uint8.
Here is the function I use to check inputs and outputs, I use batch size of 32 but print only 8 of them.

```
def generate_images(test_input):
  prediction = decoder(encoder(test_input), training=True)
  plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
  for i in range(8):
    plt.subplot(4, 8, i*2+1)
    plt.imshow(test_input[i].numpy().astype("uint8") )
    plt.subplot(4, 8, i*2+2)
    plt.imshow(prediction[i] )
  plt.axis('off')
  plt.show()
```

to call this from dataset

```
for imgs, labels in train_ds.take(1):
  generate_images( imgs)
```