# Dividing images into patches tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, image-preprocessing

I am trying to build a CNN and want to divide my input images into non-overlapping patches and then use it for training.

However, I am unsure how to combine the extraction of patches with the code below.
I believe a function like `tf.image.extract_patches` should do the trick but I am unsure how I can include it in the pipeline. It's important for me to use `flow_from_directory` as I have organised my dataset accordingly.

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,target_size=(64,64),class_mode='categorical',batch_size=64)
```

I thought of using `extract_patches_2d` from scikit but it has two issues :

1. It gives random overlapping patches
2. I need to resave all images and again reorganize my dataset (same issue as `tf.image.extract_patches` unless included in pipeline)

Comment: Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64326029/load-tensorflow-images-and-create-patches/64326684#64326684) help you?

Comment: @NicolasGervais Thanks for the response. But again I am confused how can I integrate it with flow_from_directory so that I won't have to repeat the process of reorganising data as I vary my patch size